# Android: How do you scale multiple views together?

Tags: android, view, scaling, imageview, scrollview

I'm trying to layer graphics one top of each other, like an icon over a background, with the second layer (icon) at a certain pixel offset from the top left corner of first layer (background).  Since each layer will eventually have its own animation, I'm placing each in its own View.

For my implementation I have two ImageViews, one for each layer, inside a RelativeLayout, which in turn is inside a ScrollView.  ImageViews are positioned using layout_margin relative to the top left corner (0,0).  The first ImageView is larger than the screen (background), while the second ImageView is smaller than it (icon).  ScrollView automatically resizes the first ImageView (background) since it is larger than the screen, it does not resize the second since it is smaller (icon).

I need both of them to scale together, and I also need the positioning of the second layer over the first layer to adjust itself accordingly.  This actually works well in a layer-list, but due to the animations I am forced to use Views.  How can I scale and position multiple Views together, or do I need to build my own class for something that seems like it should be fairly basic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my android application. Android has introduced new set of API's to help us on this, [setScaleX()](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX%28float%29) and [setScaleY()](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleY%28float%29).

Just call layout.getParent().setScaleX(); and layout.getParent().setScaleY();